# How to iterate through web tables using selenium and ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I want to iterate through an html table with n number rows and columns as follows:

```
<table class='table'>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Spratly Islands</td>
            <td>Vietnam</td>
            <td>Azerbaijan</td>
            <td>Georgia</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sri Lanka</td>
            <td>Israel</td>
            <td>Cyprus</td>
            <td>Yemen</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Maldives</td>
            <td>Kuwait</td>
            <td>West Malaysia</td>
            <td>Nepal</td>
          </tr>
          ...
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I want to get the column names for each row using xpath and print it. How to do this in ruby?
Thanks,
RV

Comment: What have you tried and where are you getting stuck? pseudo code... `rows = driver.findElementsByXpath("//table[@class='table']//tr"); foreach (row in rows){columns = row.findElementsByXpath("//td"); foreach(col in columns){print(col.text)}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Iterate the table in ruby, Use the following code

I assume the first row is in index 1.

```
driver.find_elements(xpath: "//table[@class='table']//tr").each.with_index(1) do |_,index|
  driver.find_elements(xpath: "//table[@class='table']//tr[#{index}]/td").each do |cell|
    puts cell.text
  end
  puts '*****'
end
```

And I suggest you to move WATIR which is very nice wrapper for Ruby Selenium-Binding which actually has the syntax for table iteration,

In WATIR, you could do,

```
b.table(class: 'table').rows.each do |row|
  row.cells.each do |cell|
    puts cell.text
  end
  puts '*****'
end
```